# Is is possible to list file characteristics from .forEach method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, nio

I'm trying to use more Java 8 syntax. I have a simple use case here, listing files recursively, where I'd like to print more than just the file name as the example shows:

```
public void listFiles(String path) {
    try {
        Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
             .filter(p -> {
                 return Files.isRegularFile(p);
             })
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call a method from the forEach method, passing the file in question as a parameter? How would I reference the file?

Edit: There was some confusion in the discussion about whether the path of each file being printed could be passed as a variable to another method.

To confirm, it can. Here's the code:

```
 public void listFiles(String path) {
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
                    .filter(p -> {
                        return Files.isRegularFile(p);
                    })
                    .forEach(p -> myMethod(p));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void myMethod(Path path) {
        System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath());
        try {
            BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
            FileTime fileTime = attr.lastModifiedTime();
            System.out.println("file date: " + fileTime);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: *passing the file in question as a parameter* Can you elaborate this part ?

Comment: It's listing the file name, but say I want to list the name and the creation date, or just do something with the file. I would like to create a method, e.g. doStuff(File file), where file would be the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the method `map` as long as you care only about one parameter passed down the pipeline.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
     .filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p))
     .map(Path::getFileName)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you can expand the method parameter into a lambda expression within the `forEach` method consuming the whole `Path` that passed through the filter (is a regular file):

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
     .filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p))
     .forEach(p -> System.out.println("Path fileName: " + p.getFileName()));
```

To avoid confusion, the variable `p` is accessible only within the scope of the `filter`/`forEach` method parameter, ie. lambda expression. See the last snippet expanded:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(""))
     .filter(path1 -> Files.isRegularFile(path1))
     .forEach(new Consumer<Path>() {
         @Override
         public void accept(final Path p) {          
             // here is the `p`. It lives only in the scope of this method                 
             System.out.println("Path fileName: " + p.getFileName());
         }});
```

Comment: I see. Could I also call a method for the forEach, with "p" as the parameter?

Comment: Of course you can. The variable `p` exists only within the scope of the `forEach` method parameter, ie. lambda expression.

Comment: Just to be clear - you can't pass the "p" parameter to a method outside of the forEach? If so, I'd probably forgo the lamda in this case - there's a fair amount of processing that's going to have to happen for each file, and it doesn't make sense to squash it all into one method. That is, if I understood correctly when you say the reference to the file can't be passed out of the forEach loop.

Comment: That's correct, you cannot pass the `p` parameter to a method outside of the `filter`/`forEach`. The method `filter` assures that only the qualified files (according to your `Predicate<Path>` will proceed to the `forEach` method, hence if you filter the unnecessary out first and process then, you use Stream API correctly.

Comment: Can you explain what "pass the `p` parameter to a method outside" is supposed to mean? I mean, *of course*  you can do something like `forEach(p -> myMethod(p))` to avoid having longer code in the lambda expression. In fact, this is even the recommended approach, which also makes the code testable.

Comment: I meant (you guess) that using the `p` outside the scope of the lambda expression `p -> myMethod(p)` is illegal. Seems I was not lucky in choosing right words. Would you care to rephrase it?

Comment: Guys, I'm not sure who's asking who what, but if I can use this syntax: forEach(p -> myMethod(p)), I'll be happy with that.